The differences among/between three types of renewable energy sources

They discussed the differences among/between three types of renewable
energy sources. [my sentence]

Which is preferable, "among" or "between"?
I tend to use "differences among" for a group", and "differences between" for a list such as "oranges, apples, and bananas" or "Judy, Mary, and Susan". But I am not sure whether I should regard "three types of renewable energy sources" as a group, hence my question.

See this usage chart showing that difference among the three was virtually unknown until a century ago. And it's still far less common than difference between the three. Note that we usually use singular difference even when there are multiple differences (which is almost inevitably the case when contrasting three or more)...

... Looking at some written instances of the less common difference among the three in the above link, many if not most seem to be science / medical / biotech contexts, usually from multiple authors with non-Anglophone names. Even actual Anglophone scientists aren't renowned for their language skills. I suggest you stick with difference/s between your subjects. And forget trying to assign some different nuance to difference/s among - just avoid it.

The idea that we suddenly needed to refer to some different kind of differences a century ago (that Victorians weren't aware of, or didn't like to write and talk about?) is ridiculously unlikely. Almost everyone would understand the more recent difference/s among as equivalent to difference/s between. I also note that the among version is very much less common in BrE than it is in AmE. No way do I believe Americans have some special alternative meaning reserved for the "somewhat marked" usage.

@FumbleFingers About the first comment of yours. Does the following sentence sound natural to you? "What are the differences between when, while, and as?"

Well, as it happens, exactly that (plural) noun phrase occurs in a technical publication. It's not a book trying to teach anyone language, though - it's exploring "The Expression of Simultaneity" from the psycho-linguistic perspective. Searching Google Books I quickly found a few written instances of difference between Britain, France, and Germany (but it's not easy to think of 3 things one might refer to differences between! :) And there were more instances for those 3 with differences.

...as expected, there are no viewable written instances of "differences among britain france and germany" in Google Books (unlike NGrams, search-terms in Google Books aren't case-sensitive). So there's no reason to think difference among is somehow more suitable if you've got multiple differences, and/or multiple things being compared. It's just an emerging (but still minority) usage.

Is the following version more idiomatic? "What is the difference between when, while, and as?"

They're both fine. No-one would think anything of it whichever plurality you use. Don't forget that when asked as a question, the implication is you don't know whether there's more than one difference, anyway! But even if you know you're about to present multiple distinguishing features, it's still perfectly acceptable to say I'm going to explain to you the difference between when, while, and as. English doesn't always care much about plurality (especially British English, wherein things like companies, governments, and sports teams can change plurality at the drop of a hat! :)

Thank you very much, @FumbleFingers. Your point is that "difference(s) among" should be avoided under any context. Is that right?

Yes - ...difference among... does occur increasingly often in recent decades, but it's still a minority usage, and few if any people will understand it to mean anything different to ...difference between..., so it's of no use to you. And at least some people will consider it a mistake, so it's got downsides, but no upsides. I personally consider the answer below is just a futile attempt to draw a distinction that doesn't really exist - it certainly wouldn't be universally recognized.

AP Styleguide has always said "between" is only for two things, "among" is for more than two. Nothing about the type of comparison (difference, similarity, whatever).

@FumbleFingers Many thanks.

@user8356 Thank you very much. Do Americans learn that "rule" in school?

@kaguyahime -- No, it's not a common grammar rule. The Associated Press (AP) is a journalism organization, its Styleguide is used by journalists for newspapers, websites, magazine, and etc. But its "rules" are also widely applicable, and more common sense than other style guides.

I've heard of The Chicago Manual of Style somewhere but never heard of AP Styleguide. Many thanks, @user8356.

The differences among a group are their disagreements, i.e. the differences of opinion shared by a group of people.
The differences between a group are the things that differentiate the members, that make each one different from the others.
Because both collocations exist and because "among" and "between" have significant semantic overlap, it would not be at all surprising to find these used with the opposite senses in the wild. But when speaking carefully, you should use "between" in your example.

Thank you very much, @Luke Sawczak. I would be very happy if you gave me an example in which "differences among" is preferable to "differences between".

@Kaguyahime I've been hearing about some differences among the staff over whether we should go forward with this plan.

Many thanks, @Luke Sawczak.
